# Replace "bad words" partly with asteriks, ignoring the case and retaining the old case

Tags: vb.net

I have a bad words replace script for VB.net that has caused many issues. After many trial and error, the current code works but will not filter out words that have caps.

```
    Private Function CheckForBadWords(ByVal InputString As String) As String
        Dim r As Regex
        Dim element As String
        Dim eLength As Integer
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim AttachtoEnd As String
        For Each element In alWordList
            r = New Regex("\b" & element)
            eLength = element.Length
            For x = 3 To eLength - 1
                AttachtoEnd = AttachtoEnd & "*"
            Next
            InputString = r.Replace(InputString, element, Left(element, 3) & AttachtoEnd)
            AttachtoEnd = ""
        Next
        Return InputString
    End Function
```

How do I make it check for words with caps in them? For example: phuck will get check where as Phuck or PHUCK will not get checked.

I tried following this tutorial but it's in C# and I barely know VB.net:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/67129-creating-a-bad-word-filter-functionality-in-aspnet-wc%23/

Adding more detail: with some help this seemed to work after multiple tweaks, but the errors remain, specifically quotes and double quotes or < br >s.

```
    Private Function CheckForBadWords(ByVal InputString As String) As String
        Dim starPosition As Integer = 0
        Dim element As String
        Dim eLength As Integer
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim AttachtoEnd As String
        Dim strArray = InputString.Split(" ")
        Dim specialChars As New List(Of String)(New String() {"@", "!", ".", ",", "(", ")", "/", "#", "$", "&", "+", "-", "_", "=", ":", "'", "*", "^", "`", "<", ">", "[", "]", "{", "}", "\", "|", ControlChars.Quote})
        Dim firstChars As String = ""
        Dim LastChars As String = ""
        InputString = String.Empty
        For Each item As String In strArray
            Dim str As String = item
            firstChars = String.Empty
            LastChars = String.Empty
            For Each ch As Char In str
                If Not specialChars.Contains(ch) Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    firstChars += ch
                End If
            Next
            For Each spChar As Char In firstChars.ToCharArray()
                str = str.Trim(spChar)
            Next
            For i As Integer = str.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If Not specialChars.Contains(str(i)) Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    LastChars = str(i) + LastChars
                End If
            Next
            For Each spChar As String In specialChars
                str = str.Trim(spChar)
            Next
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) Then
                For Each element In alWordList
                    If element.ToLower = str.ToLower Then
                        str = str.Trim()
                        eLength = element.Length
                        For x = 3 To eLength - 1
                            AttachtoEnd = AttachtoEnd & "*"
                            starPosition += 1
                        Next
                        str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - starPosition) & AttachtoEnd
                    End If
                    AttachtoEnd = ""
                    starPosition = 0
                Next
            End If
            InputString += firstChars + str + LastChars & " "
        Next
        Return InputString
    End Function
```

So now I think it is best to go back to regex, which works really well just need it too handle caps.

A final note... the words to be checked are coming in as an arraylist.

Comment: Turn all bad words into lower case. Then turn the string you're checking into lower case. Then perform the check.

Comment: You want to replace only words or also if the "bad words" are substrings like `phuckcheck`?

Comment: the current code is working for the whole string. but when the "bad" words have any type of caps in them it doesn't work right. please provide some sample codes in answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace all "bad words"words in the string with in a way that the first 3 letters remain and rest is replaced with asterisks like `phu***` and you want to compare in a case-insensitive manner;  there is no built-in method. You could use

- `Regex.Replace` with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` or
- `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Replace` with `CompareMethod.Text`.

But both have the disadvantage that they will replace the old-value with a new-value where the new-value is not keeping the old case. If the word was `PHUCK` and your "bad-word" in the list is `Phuck` it will be replaced with `Ph***` not `PH***`.

Since you have commented that this is important, the only way is to write a custom method:

```
Module StringExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ReplaceBadWords(ByVal str As String, ByVal badWords As IEnumerable(Of String), ByVal comparison As StringComparison, ByVal Optional showClearTextLength As Integer = 3, ByVal Optional obfuscateChar As Char = "*"c) As String
        Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(str)
        For Each badWord As String In badWords
            Dim index As Integer = str.IndexOf(badWord, comparison)
            While index <> -1
                Dim oldValue As String = str.Substring(index, badWord.Length)
                Dim newValue As String
                If badWord.Length > showClearTextLength Then
                    newValue = oldValue.Remove(showClearTextLength) & New String(obfuscateChar, oldValue.Length - showClearTextLength)
                Else
                    newValue = New String(obfuscateChar, oldValue.Length)
                End If

                For i As Integer = index To index + newValue.Length - 1
                    sb(i) = newValue(i - index)
                Next

                index += newValue.Length
                index = str.IndexOf(badWord, index, comparison)
            End While
        Next

        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function

End Module
```

With your (silly) sample:

```
Dim replaced = "phuck will get check where as Phuck or PHUCK".
    ReplaceBadWords({ "Phuck", "ILL" }, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Result:

```
phu** w*** get check where as Phu** or PHU**
```

A parallel version if you have a huge amount of "bad-words":

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ReplaceBadWordsParallel(ByVal str As String, ByVal badWords As IEnumerable(Of String), ByVal comparison As StringComparison, ByVal Optional showClearTextLength As Integer = 3, ByVal Optional obfuscateChar As Char = "*"c) As String
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(str)

    Parallel.ForEach(badWords, 
        Sub(badWord)
            Dim index As Integer = str.IndexOf(badWord, comparison)
            While index <> -1
                Dim oldValue As String = str.Substring(index, badWord.Length)
                Dim newValue As String
                If badWord.Length > showClearTextLength Then
                    newValue = oldValue.Remove(showClearTextLength) & New String(obfuscateChar, oldValue.Length - showClearTextLength)
                Else
                    newValue = New String(obfuscateChar, oldValue.Length)
                End If

                For i As Integer = index To index + newValue.Length - 1
                    sb(i) = newValue(i - index)
                Next

                index += newValue.Length
                index = str.IndexOf(badWord, index, comparison)
            End While
        End Sub)

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Note that i've yet **not checked if the parallel version is thread-safe** at all.

---

C# Version if someone is interested:

```
public static string ReplaceBadWords(this string str, IEnumerable<string> badWords, StringComparison comparison, int showClearTextLength = 3, char obfuscateChar = '*')
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);

    foreach (string badWord in badWords)
    {
        int index = str.IndexOf(badWord, comparison);
        while (index != -1)
        {
            string oldValue = str.Substring(index, badWord.Length);
            string newValue;
            if (badWord.Length > showClearTextLength)
            {
                newValue = oldValue.Remove(showClearTextLength) + new string(obfuscateChar, oldValue.Length - showClearTextLength);
            }
            else
            {
                newValue = new string(obfuscateChar, oldValue.Length);
            }
            for (int i = index; i < index + newValue.Length; i++)
                sb[i] = newValue[i - index];

            index += newValue.Length;
            index = str.IndexOf(badWord, index, comparison);
        }
    }           

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @7huan: i have added a parallel version. You might want to delete your older comments because i have also removed mine.

Answer (score 1):

If your initial code works just make the Regex case-insensitive:

```
r = New Regex("\b" & element, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

*Case-insensitive* means that the Regex does not care about UPPERCASE or lowercase.

For more information see the documentation for the [**Regular Expression Options**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options).